# Rails remove table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, schema

Using rails 4 and generated a table and then did a rake db:migrate to add the table to my schema.rb. However, I have destroyed the table, which removed its model and views but it still seems to appear in my schema.rb file, which is due to the migration. Is it safe to simply remove the lines from my codebase in sublime or is there a particular method for handling this in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create another migration that will revert the effects of previous one. That is, on `up` it will drop that table.

Of course, if you don't have existing production installation to care about, then you can just delete the original migration file, recreate database and pretend that table never existed.

If you do have existing database with important data, then full recreation is not an option, write the reverse migration.

Comment: so rails **generate migration drop_tablename** ?

Comment: @ssosina: yes, you could start with that.

Comment: You've suggest def up but my migration has created a def change. Does it really matter which method name I use? And within the method i'd simply do **drop_table :example** right? Sorry for the question i'm fairly new to rails but slowly getting there

Comment: Yes, just put `drop_table :example` inside of `change` method.